# Prosperity - Cornucopia card set

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity, dominion-cornucopia

Normally the game rule book provides balanced setup to play with different extensions. We just bought Cornucopia, but the French rule book did not provided a setup to play with Prosperity.

We would like to know if there is any idea on an interesting setup to use with these two extensions.

We use the Dominion Intrigue as our base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no "official" kingdom sets for Prosperity and Cornucopia. Personally, I like it when both Tournament (from Cornucopia) and Colonies (from Prosperity) are out, because it tempts people to try to buy some Provinces and end the game on piles. Even more interesting if Bishop is out, so you could potentially trash the Provinces for decent points.

I'd recommend just playing random sets until you find interactions you like. For generating random sets, I like http://www.hiwiller.com/dominion/, but there's lots of other tools out there.